# Le superlatif + subjonctif ou indicatif?

Tags: subjonctif, superlatifs, indicatif

Dans le livre «Nouvelle Grammaire du Français» (traduit), il est écrit que:

> 1. Ils habitent dans la plus haute tour que vous **trouverez** à gauche en sortant du métro.
> 2. C'est la plus haute tour qu'on **ait** construite à Paris.

Je ne comprends pas quand on utilise le subjonctif ou l'indicatif après le superlatif. Ils semblent très semblables.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1- Il s'agit de deux énoncés informatifs. 'Ils habitent la tour la plus haute' nous informe sur la taille de la tour. On aurait pu avoir 'Ils habitent la plus petite tour.'

'Vous trouverez cette tour à droite en sortant du métro' nous informe sur le lieu où se trouve la tour. On aurait pu avoir 'à gauche en sortant du métro'.

'La plus haute' et 'à droite en sortant du métro' sont deux informations nouvelles, indépendantes l'une de l'autre. Elles ne sont pas reprises. La deuxième partie de l'énoncé ne sert pas à commenter la première.

Les deux informations sont seulement reliées par le pronom relatif 'que' pour éviter d'avoir à répéter 'la tour la plus haute'. Comme dans:

Ils habitent la tour la plus haute. Vous trouverez la tour la plus haute à droite en sortant du métro.

2- Information déjà connue, qui n'est pas nouvelle: Une tour a été construite.

Je reprends cette information au subjonctif pour faire un commentaire sur celle-ci: C'est la plus haute.

J'utilise le subjonctif pour souligner qu'il ne s'agit pas de faire connaître la construction de la tour mais d'apporter dans l'autre partie de l'énoncé qui, elle, est à l'indicatif, une information nouvelle : c'est la plus haute.

C'est la tour la plus haute... information nouvelle qui peut être contredite

... qui ait été construite à Paris
Sa construction est un fait acquis qui ne peut pas être remis en cause, ce n'est pas une information nouvelle, c'est une reprise, d'où l'emploi du subjonctif.

Comment: Donc si l'on veut souligner que la tour est la plus haute, est-ce qu'on peut dire `Ils habitent dans la plus haute tour que vous puissiez trouver à gauche en sortant du métro.` (among those on the left side of the underground station)?